# Article before year in 'several months or year'

Tags: articles

I noticed that it is written both ways, for example:

I have enough to last me for the next several months or year.
I have enough to last me for the next several months or **a** year.

My question is are both forms correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your specific example is missing an article.

Because *months* is plural, it should be "several months or **a** year" to denote that it isn't "several years".

In other situations involving lists of singular items you don't always need to repeat the article, for example, "you may take one apple or banana".